# Inserir nome de imagens do sistema de arquivos no mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, exportação

Eu uso Debian, e preciso capturar o nome das imagens de uma pasta e inserir os nomes(como string) em uma tabela mysql.

```
ss:~/folder_img$
859034809583_img.jpg
458389547389_img.jpg
...
```

Esse problema surgiu agora e não tenho ideia de como resolver.

Não busco um script, apenas uma luz.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma seria utilizar um script `bash` que monta os comandos de `INSERT` e passa como entrada para o cliente `mysql`, como por exemplo:

```
ls ~/folder_img \
| xargs -I{} echo "INSERT INTO imagens (arquivo) VALUES ('{}');" \
| mysql -u [usuario] -p [senha]
```

Caso tal carga seja recorrente, como por exemplo um processo agendado via `crontab`, é interessante passar a senha por parâmetro ou utilizar outra forma de autenticação automática ([lendo um arquivo protegido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916074/how-to-pass-password-from-file-to-mysql-command), talvez), para que o `mysql` execute sem abrir *prompt* de senha.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção vou testar...

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que seus arquivos de imagens estejam contidos em um único diretório:

```
$ ls -al ./folder_img/*.png 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lacobus lacobus  349237 Jul  4 18:03 ./folder_img/alpha.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lacobus lacobus  312568 Jul  4 18:03 ./folder_img/beta.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lacobus lacobus  159315 Jul  4 18:03 ./folder_img/delta.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lacobus lacobus 2453952 Jul  4 18:03 ./folder_img/episilon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lacobus lacobus  482526 Jul  4 18:03 ./folder_img/gamma.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lacobus lacobus  848590 Jul  4 18:03 ./folder_img/omega.pn
```

Você pode usar o utilitário `find` para gerar um script SQL a partir dos arquivos de imagem contidos nesse diretório, de forma não recursiva. O exemplo a seguir grava um script SQL no arquivo `script.sql`, veja só:

```
$ find ./folder_img -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.png" -type f -exec \
echo "INSERT INTO tb_imagem (nome_arquivo) VALUES ('{}');" \; > script.sql
```

Saída (`script.sql`):

```
INSERT INTO tb_imagem (nome_arquivo) VALUES ('./folder_img/delta.png');
INSERT INTO tb_imagem (nome_arquivo) VALUES ('./folder_img/alpha.png');
INSERT INTO tb_imagem (nome_arquivo) VALUES ('./folder_img/gamma.png');
INSERT INTO tb_imagem (nome_arquivo) VALUES ('./folder_img/beta.png');
INSERT INTO tb_imagem (nome_arquivo) VALUES ('./folder_img/episilon.png');
INSERT INTO tb_imagem (nome_arquivo) VALUES ('./folder_img/omega.png');
```

Para executar o script gerado no seu banco de dados:

```
$ mysql -h [servidor] -u [usuario] -p [senha] -D [database] < script.sql
```

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, mas e o banco de dados?

Comment: O script gerado está em formato `ANSI SQL` e pode ser executado em virtualmente qualquer banco de dados. Como você não especificou a estrutura de dados da tabela e os parametros de conexao com o seu banco de dados, fica dificil ajudar mais.

Comment: é mysql bota um exemplo só pra eu ver a sintaxe, pls, digo no acesso ao bd e a base de dados..

Comment: @MagicHat: Feito!

Comment: nice vou testar vlw man